# Can I list my usb content without mounting it?

Tags: mount, usb, devices, block-device, usb-device

I am wondering if there was a way to list files on a device without mounting it (i.e la output )

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It is an very useful tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sort of. There are tools like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) that operate on block devices direclty without mounting them.